# Windows Phone App 8. Can't display data in xaml markup

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

I've been able to transfer objects between pages with ease, but now I can't display the data in the xaml markup.

Here's the Quote entity that's stored in a sdf-file on the application:

```
[Table]
    public class Quote
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string QuoteOfTheDay { get; set; }


        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public string SaidBy { get; set; }


        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string Context { get; set; }


        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string Episode { get; set; }


        [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
        public string Season { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    DataContext = this;

    var quote = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["q"];             

    Quote quoteToDisplay = (Quote)quote;       
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty QuoteToDisplayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "QuoteToDisplay", typeof(Quote), typeof(PhoneApplicationPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(Quote)));

public Quote QuouteToDisplay
{
    get { return (Quote)GetValue(QuoteToDisplayProperty); }
    set { SetValue(QuoteToDisplayProperty, value); }
}
```

The xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Text="{Binding QuoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay}" />
    </Grid>
```

I got the exact data that I want to display in the xaml. I want to display the QuoteOfTheDay property in the TextBlock. But everytime I try to use {Binding}, the TextBlock is always empty. When I also try to use Binding, intellisense doesn't suggest 
"QuoteOfTheDay".

I've obviuosly missed something important, but I can't really see what it is.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at you code shows several problems:

1. You are initializing a TextBlock in your C# code, giving it the same name as the TextBlock you defined in XAML. This means you're not changing any of the properties of the XAML TextBlock which is the one that is actually shown.
2. You are specifying a DataContext for your TextBlock to be `quoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay`, but then your binding statement in XAML is `{Binding quoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay}`, which means you're trying to bind into a non existing hierarchy `quoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay.quoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay`. You're probably getting a BindingExpression error in the Output windows due to this mistake.

What I would do is this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    DataContext = this;

    var quote = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["q"];

    QuoteToDisplay = (Quote)quote;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty QuoteToDisplayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "QuoteToDisplay", typeof (Quote), typeof (MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(Quote)));

public Quote QuoteToDisplay
{
    get { return (Quote) GetValue(QuoteToDisplayProperty); }
    set { SetValue(QuoteToDisplayProperty, value); }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Text="{Binding QuoteToDisplay.QuoteOfTheDay}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the "MyFilterLogic" Parameter that is required.

Why do you have to make a FilterLogic class for the Register method?

Comment: I was just writing almost the same thing. :) Only one difference - I'm not a fan of overwriting the DataContext of Pages/UserControls. I'd prefer to change the DataContext of the Grid or the TextBlock. Or set the Binding in code (if I want to bind to the current Page/UserControl, and not to it's original DataContext).

Comment: Thanks @eshaham, but unfortunately I keep getting the same error.

No quote is displayed on the page at all in the textblock.

Comment: Well no error really, but the same problem as before. No text is displayed in the TextBlock on the page for some reason.

Comment: I don't see anything, do you have any BindingExpression errors, or other exceptions in the output window?

Comment: @eshaham I found in the output window this exception

System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ItemName' property not found on 'Beavis_and_Butthead_Quote_of_the_Day.MainPage' 'Beavis_and_Butthead_Quote_of_the_Day.MainPage' (HashCode=58206383). BindingExpression: Path='ItemName' DataItem='Beavis_and_Butthead_Quote_of_the_Day.MainPage' (HashCode=58206383); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..

Comment: I made another update to the c# part, but it looks to me that the error is showing the binding expression you have on the TextBlock is different than what you have written in your question. The reason I suspect it is different is because the error mentions, ItemName which doesn't appear in your original XAML.

Comment: @eshaham, I've been away for a while but now I've come back to try to solve this.

When I was debugging the application, I noticed that the dependency property is null. The QuoteToDisplay Property is also null for some reason.

How do I find and set the ItemName property?

Comment: @Assassin87 sorry, now it was my turn to be away for a while... :-) I hope you solved your problem by now. If not, please update your post with a more complete sample - I don't know what ItemName stands for, I assume it has something to do with your code.

Comment: @eshaham, I solved it without using a dependency property. I just assigned the text property value in the code behind.

Sometimes, all you have to do is to shut down emulator, and then restart it the next time you debug the application. It worked fine then :)

Comment: @assassin87 great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use {Binding} if you assign .Text property in code-behind ? I think you you must remove binding from xaml or (and it's better way) use MVVM.